# Scroll settings not maintaining after first time loading in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable inside a bootsrap modalpopup. While clicking an icon in a row in Grid, the modalpopup will be opened and the jquery datatable will be displaying inside the popup with the setting which i applied. But when i click on the another icon(which is in another row in Grid), the jquery datatable in the modalpopup applies all settings which i specified, except scroll settings. Please check the screenshots and code below. How to fix this issue?

**With Scrollbar:**

[image: with scrollbar]

**Without scrollbar:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
 $(function () {
        $('#editstorelist').dataTable({
            "bDestroy":true,
            "sScrollY": "15vh",
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bSort": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            'bLengthChange': false,
            "iDisplayLength": 4,
            "aaSorting": [],
            "aoColumns": [
                { sWidth: '15%' },
                { sWidth: '9%' },
                { sWidth: '19%' },
                { sWidth: '6%' }
            ],

        });

    });
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, scroll is only applied when necessary.

Comment: @ZenCodr : No. Scroll is not displaying even for more than 4 records in the Grid. Actually scroll related element('<div id='scrollTableElement'/>') not rendering in Grid after first time loading.